Creating top down shooter and having the bullets move towards the mouse direction indefinitely
I'm trying to create a top down shooter in Unity for a college project and am having an issue programming a shooting mechanic, below is the script for the bullet prefab that's suppose to make the bullet move in the direction that the player's mouse was at upon instantiation.
I was able to use some code from one of unity's online tutorials for having an object move towards the mouse position, the issue is that once it reaches the mouse position it stops. I need to know how to make it so that it moves towards the direction of the mouse position, then keeps moving in the same direction indefinitely?
public class Shoot : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int speed;
    Vector3 mp;
    Vector2 md;
    float mA;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Awake()
    {
        mp = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        md = mp - transform.position;
        mA = Vector2.SignedAngle(Vector2.up, md);
        transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, mA);
    }
    

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        transform.position = 
         Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, mp, speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}


Well the key point is, you tell it to move to an exact position, then wonder why it stops when it gets there..  What you need to do is tell it to move in a direction..

If the bullet is facing the direction you want it to move, you can simply use transform.forward to move it in that direction indefinitely.

Create a ray cast command when firing using your players Transform.position.forward as the destination of the ray and the players position as the origin of the ray.
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastCommand.html
If the ray cast hits a collider you want and not a wall or something, animate using the same transform.position.forward as the projectile direction.

You already have your direction in md.
So instead of
transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, mp, speed * Time.deltaTime);
    

simply do
transform.position += (Vector3)md.normalized * speed * Time.deltaTime;

or alternatively assuming from your Z rotation this should behave the same
transform.position += transform.up * speed * Time.deltaTime;

